# Scrapy post request 500 Internal server

Tags: python, scrapy

I can successfully send Post request and receive all data through python requests module.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'split': 'n',
    'split_tcv': 'n',
    '__vst': '747e3d5a-52bd-4404-8290-0541c8ae3e8d',
    'permutive-id': '83d956ce-dcc4-4013-ba11-deaa916d1d11',
    'ab.storage.userId.7cc9d032-9d6d-44cf-a8f5-d276489af322': '%7B%22g%22%3A%22visitor_747e3d5a-52bd-4404-8290-0541c8ae3e8d%22%2C%22c%22%3A1647078965078%2C%22l%22%3A1648673046950%7D',
    'ab.storage.sessionId.7cc9d032-9d6d-44cf-a8f5-d276489af322': '%7B%22g%22%3A%2279a8b95e-56ac-5536-8f6d-5a63de27b982%22%2C%22e%22%3A1648674868938%2C%22c%22%3A1648673046947%2C%22l%22%3A1648673068938%7D',
    'ab.storage.deviceId.7cc9d032-9d6d-44cf-a8f5-d276489af322': '%7B%22g%22%3A%22ea184537-7399-0e15-1556-b3839d293b53%22%2C%22c%22%3A1647078965081%2C%22l%22%3A1648673046950%7D',
    '_pxvid': 'a344163f-a1ea-11ec-a1b4-516177714d73',
    'g_state': '{"i_p":1649259615738,"i_l":3}',
    '__split': '64',
    'G_ENABLED_IDPS': 'google',
    'AMCV_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg': '-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19082%7CMCMID%7C05773401507726959754212551189522089328%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1648761666s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0',
    'threshold_value': '74',
    'clstr': '',
    'clstr_tcv': '',
    'CSAT_RENTALS': 'true',
    '__fp': '57f929a2b9fe50bc016ff3280cdc0a79',
    '__snn': 'b9699e1f-99c3-44b9-b25a-f57e30a93a23',
    '__ssnstarttime': '1648754211',
    'recent_searches': '%5B%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T16%3A10%3A05.597Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T18%3A19%3A49.021Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Studio%20City%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291604%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291604%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2291604%22%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T18%3A21%3A43.199Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A19%3A48.210Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22city%22%3A%22Studio%20City%22%2C%22county%22%3A%22Los%20Angeles%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291604%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291604%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22for_rent%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2291604%22%2C%22prop_status%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22isSavable%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A22%3A59.176Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A23%3A43.750Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22San%20Diego%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2292101%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2292101%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2292101%22%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T20%3A44%3A18.721Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T20%3A44%3A18.721Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22city%22%3A%22Chula%20Vista%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22centroid%22%3A%7B%22lon%22%3A-116.985898%2C%22lat%22%3A32.619087%7D%2C%22srp_link%22%3A%22%2Frealestateandhomes-search%2F91913%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22for_sale%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22user_query%22%3A%7B%22search_query%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%5B%22for_sale%22%2C%22ready_to_build%22%5D%2C%22primary%22%3Atrue%2C%22search_location%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%2291913%2C%20Chula%20Vista%2C%20CA%22%7D%7D%2C%22search_params%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22discovery_mode%22%3Afalse%2C%22location%22%3A%2291913%2C%20Chula%20Vista%2C%20CA%22%7D%7D%2C%22srp_link%22%3A%22%2Frealestateandhomes-search%2F91913%22%2C%22isSavable%22%3Atrue%2C%22id%22%3A%2291913%22%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T22%3A45%3A41.450Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T22%3A46%3A09.195Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22San%20Diego%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2292123%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2292123%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A22%3A11.736Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-31T19%3A21%3A06.151Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Chula%20Vista%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291913%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2291913%22%7D%5D',
    'AMCVS_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg': '1',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    # Already added when you pass json=
    # 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.realtor.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'Referer': 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/779-Eastshore-Ter-Unit-232_Chula-Vista_CA_91913_M23699-12806',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'split=n; split_tcv=n; __vst=747e3d5a-52bd-4404-8290-0541c8ae3e8d; permutive-id=83d956ce-dcc4-4013-ba11-deaa916d1d11; ab.storage.userId.7cc9d032-9d6d-44cf-a8f5-d276489af322=%7B%22g%22%3A%22visitor_747e3d5a-52bd-4404-8290-0541c8ae3e8d%22%2C%22c%22%3A1647078965078%2C%22l%22%3A1648673046950%7D; ab.storage.sessionId.7cc9d032-9d6d-44cf-a8f5-d276489af322=%7B%22g%22%3A%2279a8b95e-56ac-5536-8f6d-5a63de27b982%22%2C%22e%22%3A1648674868938%2C%22c%22%3A1648673046947%2C%22l%22%3A1648673068938%7D; ab.storage.deviceId.7cc9d032-9d6d-44cf-a8f5-d276489af322=%7B%22g%22%3A%22ea184537-7399-0e15-1556-b3839d293b53%22%2C%22c%22%3A1647078965081%2C%22l%22%3A1648673046950%7D; _pxvid=a344163f-a1ea-11ec-a1b4-516177714d73; g_state={"i_p":1649259615738,"i_l":3}; __split=64; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; AMCV_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19082%7CMCMID%7C05773401507726959754212551189522089328%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1648761666s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0; threshold_value=74; clstr=; clstr_tcv=; CSAT_RENTALS=true; __fp=57f929a2b9fe50bc016ff3280cdc0a79; __snn=b9699e1f-99c3-44b9-b25a-f57e30a93a23; __ssnstarttime=1648754211; recent_searches=%5B%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T16%3A10%3A05.597Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T18%3A19%3A49.021Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Studio%20City%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291604%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291604%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2291604%22%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T18%3A21%3A43.199Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A19%3A48.210Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22city%22%3A%22Studio%20City%22%2C%22county%22%3A%22Los%20Angeles%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291604%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291604%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22for_rent%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2291604%22%2C%22prop_status%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22isSavable%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A22%3A59.176Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A23%3A43.750Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22San%20Diego%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2292101%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2292101%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2292101%22%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T20%3A44%3A18.721Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T20%3A44%3A18.721Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22city%22%3A%22Chula%20Vista%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22centroid%22%3A%7B%22lon%22%3A-116.985898%2C%22lat%22%3A32.619087%7D%2C%22srp_link%22%3A%22%2Frealestateandhomes-search%2F91913%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22for_sale%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22user_query%22%3A%7B%22search_query%22%3A%7B%22status%22%3A%5B%22for_sale%22%2C%22ready_to_build%22%5D%2C%22primary%22%3Atrue%2C%22search_location%22%3A%7B%22location%22%3A%2291913%2C%20Chula%20Vista%2C%20CA%22%7D%7D%2C%22search_params%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22discovery_mode%22%3Afalse%2C%22location%22%3A%2291913%2C%20Chula%20Vista%2C%20CA%22%7D%7D%2C%22srp_link%22%3A%22%2Frealestateandhomes-search%2F91913%22%2C%22isSavable%22%3Atrue%2C%22id%22%3A%2291913%22%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T22%3A45%3A41.450Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T22%3A46%3A09.195Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22San%20Diego%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2292123%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2292123%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%7B%22items_viewed%22%3A0%2C%22first_ran%22%3A%222022-03-30T19%3A22%3A11.736Z%22%2C%22last_ran%22%3A%222022-03-31T19%3A21%3A06.151Z%22%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22area_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Chula%20Vista%22%2C%22state_id%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22state_code%22%3A%22CA%22%2C%22postal_code%22%3A%2291913%22%2C%22slug_id%22%3A%2291913%22%7D%2C%22resource_type%22%3A%22pdp%22%2C%22search_type%22%3A%22postal_code%22%2C%22isAjax%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2291913%22%7D%5D; AMCVS_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg=1',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

params = {
    'client_id': 'rdc-x',
    'schema': 'vesta',
}

json_data = {
    'query': '{\n    home(property_id: "2369912806") {\n      advertisers {\n        team_name\n        address {\n          city\n          country\n          line\n          postal_code\n          state\n          state_code\n        }\n        builder {\n          fulfillment_id\n        }\n        broker {\n          accent_color\n          designations\n          fulfillment_id\n          name\n          logo\n        }\n        email\n        fulfillment_id\n        href\n        mls_set\n        name\n        nrds_id\n        office {\n          address {\n            city\n            coordinate {\n              lat\n              lon\n            }\n            country\n            line\n            postal_code\n            state\n            state_code\n          }\n          application_url\n          email\n          lead_email {\n            to\n            cc\n          }\n          fulfillment_id\n          hours\n          href\n          mls_set\n          out_of_community\n          name\n          phones {\n            ext\n            number\n            primary\n            trackable\n            type\n          }\n          photo {\n            href\n          }\n          slogan\n        }\n        phones {\n          ext\n          number\n          primary\n          trackable\n          type\n        }\n        photo {\n          href\n        }\n        slogan\n        type\n      }\n      buyers {\n        address {\n          city\n          country\n          line\n          postal_code\n          state\n          state_code\n        }\n        broker {\n          accent_color\n          designations\n          fulfillment_id\n          name\n          logo\n        }\n        email\n        fulfillment_id\n        href\n        mls_set\n        name\n        nrds_id\n        office {\n          address {\n            city\n            coordinate {\n              lat\n              lon\n            }\n            country\n            line\n            postal_code\n            state\n            state_code\n          }\n          application_url\n          email\n          lead_email {\n            to\n            cc\n          }\n          fulfillment_id\n          hours\n          href\n          mls_set\n          out_of_community\n          name\n          phones {\n            ext\n            number\n            primary\n            trackable\n            type\n          }\n          photo {\n            href\n          }\n          slogan\n        }\n        phones {\n          ext\n          number\n          primary\n          trackable\n          type\n        }\n        photo {\n          href\n        }\n        slogan\n        type\n      }\n      community {\n        permalink\n      }\n      estimates {\n        current_values(source: "corelogic")\n        @include_if(field: "status", operator: in, value: "sold,off_market,other") {\n          estimate\n          estimate_high\n          estimate_low\n          date\n          source {\n            type\n            name\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      days_on_market\n      description {\n        baths\n        baths_3qtr\n        baths_full\n        baths_full_calc\n        baths_half\n        baths_max\n        baths_min\n        baths_partial_calc\n        baths_total\n        beds\n        beds_max\n        beds_min\n        construction\n        cooling\n        exterior\n        fireplace\n        garage\n        garage_max\n        garage_min\n        garage_type\n        heating\n        logo {\n          href\n        }\n        lot_sqft\n        name\n        pool\n        roofing\n        rooms\n        sqft\n        sqft_max\n        sqft_min\n        stories\n        styles\n        sub_type\n        text\n        type\n        units\n        year_built\n        year_renovated\n        zoning\n      }\n      details {\n        category\n        parent_category\n        text\n      }\n      flags {\n        is_coming_soon\n        is_contingent\n        is_deal_available\n        is_for_rent\n        is_foreclosure\n        is_garage_present\n        is_new_construction\n        is_pending\n        is_price_excludes_land\n        is_senior_community\n        is_short_sale\n        is_subdivision\n      }\n      href\n      last_sold_date\n      last_sold_price\n      list_date\n      list_price\n      listing_id\n      local {\n        flood {\n          firststreet_url\n          fsid\n          flood_factor_score\n          flood_factor_severity\n          environmental_risk\n          trend_direction\n          fema_zone\n          insurance_quotes{\n            provider_url\n            provider_name\n            provider_logo\n            expires\n            price\n            home_coverage\n            contents_coverage\n            disclaimer\n          }\n        }\n        noise {\n          score\n        }\n      }\n      location {\n        address {\n          city\n          coordinate {\n            lat\n            lon\n          }\n          country\n          line\n          postal_code\n          state\n          state_code\n          street_direction\n          street_name\n          street_number\n          street_post_direction\n          street_suffix\n          unit\n          validation_code\n        }\n        county {\n          fips_code\n          name\n          state_code\n        }\n        neighborhoods {\n          city\n          id\n          level\n          name\n          state_code\n          slug_id\n        }\n        search_areas {\n          city\n          state_code\n        }\n      }\n      nearby_schools {\n        schools {\n          coordinate {\n            lat\n            lon\n          }\n          distance_in_miles\n          district {\n            id\n            name\n          }\n          education_levels\n          funding_type\n          grades\n          greatschools_id\n          id\n          name\n          nces_code\n          parent_rating\n          rating\n          review_count\n          slug_id\n          student_count\n        }\n      }\n      photo_count\n      photos {\n        title\n        description\n        href\n        type\n      }\n      primary_photo {\n        href\n      }\n      property_history {\n        date\n        event_name\n        price\n        price_sqft\n        source_listing_id\n        source_name\n        listing @include_if(field: "status", operator: in, value: "sold,off_market,other") {\n          list_price\n          last_status_change_date\n          last_update_date\n          status\n          list_date\n          listing_id\n          suppression_flags\n          photos {\n            href\n          }\n          description {\n            text\n          }\n          advertisers {\n            fulfillment_id\n            nrds_id\n            name\n            email\n            href\n            slogan\n            office {\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              email\n              href\n              slogan\n              out_of_community\n              application_url\n              mls_set\n            }\n            broker {\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              accent_color\n              logo\n            }\n            type\n            mls_set\n          }\n          buyers {\n            fulfillment_id\n            nrds_id\n            name\n            email\n            href\n            slogan\n            type\n            mls_set\n            address {\n              line\n              city\n              postal_code\n              state_code\n              state\n              country\n              coordinate {\n                lat\n                lon\n              }\n            }\n            office {\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              email\n              href\n              slogan\n              hours\n              out_of_community\n              application_url\n              mls_set\n              address {\n                line\n                city\n                postal_code\n                state_code\n                state\n                country\n              }\n              phones {\n                number\n                type\n                primary\n                trackable\n                ext\n              }\n              county {\n                name\n              }\n            }\n            phones {\n              number\n              type\n              primary\n              trackable\n              ext\n            }\n            broker {\n              fulfillment_id\n              name\n              accent_color\n              logo\n            }\n          }\n          source {\n            id\n            agents {\n              agent_id\n              agent_name\n              office_id\n              office_name\n              office_phone\n              type\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      property_id\n      provider_url {\n        href\n        level\n        type\n      }\n      source {\n        agents {\n          agent_id\n          agent_name\n          id\n          office_id\n          office_name\n          office_phone\n          type\n        }\n        disclaimer {\n          href\n          logo {\n            href\n            height\n            width\n          }\n          text\n        }\n        id\n        plan_id\n        listing_id\n        name\n        raw {\n          status\n          style\n          tax_amount\n        }\n        type\n        community_id\n      }\n      status\n      suppression_flags\n      tags\n      tax_history {\n        assessment {\n          building\n          land\n          total\n        }\n        market {\n          building\n          land\n          total\n        }\n        tax\n        year\n      }\n    }\n  }',
    'variables': {},
    'callfrom': 'PDP',
    'isClient': True,
}

response = requests.post('https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, json=json_data)
```

This post request returns neat **json** dict.

I tried removing new lines and strip the unwanted spaces from `json_data['query']` string but by cleaning the query string it gives **400** response.

When I use the same in scrapy I got **500** error. Here is my Scrapy code.

```
>>> from scrapy import Request
>>> from urllib.parse import urlencode
>>> url = 'https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?' + urlencode(params)
>>> r = Request(url=url, method='POST', body=json.dumps(json_data), cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
>>> fetch(r)
```

Error:

```
2022-04-01 00:35:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2022-04-01 00:35:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2022-04-01 00:35:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <POST https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2022-04-01 00:35:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <POST https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk?client_id=rdc-x&schema=vesta> (referer: https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/779-Eastshore-Ter-Unit-232_Chula-Vista_CA_91913_M23699-12806)
```

There is another post request from the same api endpoint which is neat and clean but not all the data in it specifically I am after. Here is the code:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'split': 'n',
    'split_tcv': '143',
    '__vst': '152dcbd8-0835-4216-8fb0-08acbd3d84cb',
    '__ssn': '363de20b-632d-44df-8a7e-710530f17aca',
    '__ssnstarttime': '1648756568',
    '__split': '49',
    'G_ENABLED_IDPS': 'google',
    'pxcts': '9f300f24-b12c-11ec-acd0-6d6763416465',
    '_pxvid': '9f3002da-b12c-11ec-acd0-6d6763416465',
    '_fbp': 'fb.1.1648756575432.190210113',
    's_ecid': 'MCMID%7C02791291578246133719093373803026546195',
    'AMCVS_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg': '1',
    '__fp': '3f685e7829acae9bfd1b24cc585822f2',
    '_pxff_bdd': '2000',
    '_pxff_cde': '5,10',
    'srchID': 'c1621829c2ba44eeaf6730f485681000',
    'criteria': 'pg%3D1%26sprefix%3D%252Frealestateandhomes-search%26area_type%3Dcity%26search_type%3Dcity%26city%3DLos%2520Angeles%26state_code%3DCA%26state_id%3DCA%26lat%3D34.0193936%26long%3D-118.4108248%26county_fips%3D06037%26county_fips_multi%3D06037%26loc%3DLos%2520Angeles%252C%2520CA%26locSlug%3DLos-Angeles_CA%26county_needed_for_uniq%3Dfalse',
    'user_activity': 'return',
    'last_ran': '-1',
    'last_ran_threshold': '1648756647928',
    'AMCV_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg': '-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19083%7CMCMID%7C02791291578246133719093373803026546195%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1648763850s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0',
    '_px3': '58197ee5ca6ae8cbda1bc68ab010ab5904d51ef28caab952f12e1404be5e6d8d:mUP+py2YqvMEeklbv4mq/DiHWSgUe4L8Xv96S935fYZ3bvsPObKY9AS52EOZkVABZx1qkwAkoez6rcs8069F8Q==:1000:AW3uJyae1jL3UWtkn9QKYWs1b7EbIVN8qGQHX5trb1NKOPHiJNpqayoDXtaZ1BoiDGbq1JsSBvWtug3vKcLVWEXi53XECTZVNMgC3H9pJcN6gFUsLyZiTRiDsA+ZuZcFkHrYpm1vtKeYAMgxlHId23nBDicSlnJ9JeB9SN1/CaBdrMbUPcOtsbKCmpU1puXo0pCuuGIe+wWaalpDoqyPRg==',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.realtor.com',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    # Already added when you pass json=
    # 'content-type': 'application/json',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'cookie': 'split=n; split_tcv=143; __vst=152dcbd8-0835-4216-8fb0-08acbd3d84cb; __ssn=363de20b-632d-44df-8a7e-710530f17aca; __ssnstarttime=1648756568; __split=49; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; pxcts=9f300f24-b12c-11ec-acd0-6d6763416465; _pxvid=9f3002da-b12c-11ec-acd0-6d6763416465; _fbp=fb.1.1648756575432.190210113; s_ecid=MCMID%7C02791291578246133719093373803026546195; AMCVS_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg=1; __fp=3f685e7829acae9bfd1b24cc585822f2; _pxff_bdd=2000; _pxff_cde=5,10; srchID=c1621829c2ba44eeaf6730f485681000; criteria=pg%3D1%26sprefix%3D%252Frealestateandhomes-search%26area_type%3Dcity%26search_type%3Dcity%26city%3DLos%2520Angeles%26state_code%3DCA%26state_id%3DCA%26lat%3D34.0193936%26long%3D-118.4108248%26county_fips%3D06037%26county_fips_multi%3D06037%26loc%3DLos%2520Angeles%252C%2520CA%26locSlug%3DLos-Angeles_CA%26county_needed_for_uniq%3Dfalse; user_activity=return; last_ran=-1; last_ran_threshold=1648756647928; AMCV_8853394255142B6A0A4C98A4%40AdobeOrg=-1124106680%7CMCIDTS%7C19083%7CMCMID%7C02791291578246133719093373803026546195%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1648763850s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.2.0; _px3=58197ee5ca6ae8cbda1bc68ab010ab5904d51ef28caab952f12e1404be5e6d8d:mUP+py2YqvMEeklbv4mq/DiHWSgUe4L8Xv96S935fYZ3bvsPObKY9AS52EOZkVABZx1qkwAkoez6rcs8069F8Q==:1000:AW3uJyae1jL3UWtkn9QKYWs1b7EbIVN8qGQHX5trb1NKOPHiJNpqayoDXtaZ1BoiDGbq1JsSBvWtug3vKcLVWEXi53XECTZVNMgC3H9pJcN6gFUsLyZiTRiDsA+ZuZcFkHrYpm1vtKeYAMgxlHId23nBDicSlnJ9JeB9SN1/CaBdrMbUPcOtsbKCmpU1puXo0pCuuGIe+wWaalpDoqyPRg==',
    'newrelic': 'eyJ2IjpbMCwxXSwiZCI6eyJ0eSI6IkJyb3dzZXIiLCJhYyI6IjM3ODU4NCIsImFwIjoiMTI5NzQxMzUyIiwiaWQiOiI0ZDk3N2RmNjg2ZWI5NjMwIiwidHIiOiI4NjMxYTMzMGYzODExZDg3YjdmZWExMWM2NzIzMzg4MCIsInRpIjoxNjQ4NzU2NjU3MDA5LCJ0ayI6IjEwMjI2ODEifX0=',
    'origin': 'https://www.realtor.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/8522-N-Adir-Dr_Canoga-Park_CA_91304_M10239-84718?ex=2941654578',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-gpc': '1',
    'traceparent': '00-8631a330f3811d87b7fea11c67233880-4d977df686eb9630-01',
    'tracestate': '1022681@nr=0-1-378584-129741352-4d977df686eb9630----1648756657009',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'client_id': 'rdc-x',
    'schema': 'vesta',
}

json_data = {
    'query': None,
    'propertyId': '1023984718',
    'callfrom': 'LDP',
    'nrQueryType': 'MAIN_QV',
    'user_id': None,
    'variables': {
        'propertyId': '1023984718',
        'relatedHomesQuery': {
            'type': 'similar_homes',
        },
        'query': {
            'type': 'home',
            'property_id': '1023984718',
        },
        'listing_id': '2941654578',
    },
    'seoPayload': {
        'pageType': {
            'silo': 'detail_page',
            'status': 'for_sale',
        },
    },
    'queryLoader': {
        'appType': 'FOR_SALE',
        'pageType': 'LDP',
        'serviceType': 'MAIN_QV',
    },
    'isClient': True,
}

response = requests.post('https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/hulk', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, json=json_data)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is the "query" in your `json_data` supposed to be valid JSON?  Because it certainly is not.  Also, you are not passing your cookies to scrapy's Request.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the cookie parameter on the post I tried it with cookies but the response is same 500. I edited the post. And yes it supposed to be valid json

Comment: Can you share the base url? It's just single page and post request not sending valid data.

Comment: [This is the link](https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/779-Eastshore-Ter-Unit-232_Chula-Vista_CA_91913_M23699-12806) where I am getting this post request. From requests module it working perfectly and I have no idea how this query string working.

Comment: The query string looks like a graphql like query. I don't think you can just turn it into JSON data and expect it to work.

Comment: So is there something we can do to make it work? I have worked with graphql queries previously  but this string is totally different to me and I can't hack my way into it it's been days and I am still blank.